# Entity Framework (Telerik) call fails with ExecuteNonQuery to PostgreSQL stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, stored-procedures, telerik

(PostgreSQL 9.1, Telerik OpenAccess v2.0.50727, PgAdmin III).

I'm having difficulty calling a stored procedure from the (Telerik) Entity Framework. The exact error is:

> NpgsqlException was unhandled by user code.
>
> ERROR: 42703: column "cpatient" does not exist.

The Telerik templated call is:

```
public int SaveDx(string cpatient, Object o, Object n)
    {
        OAParameter parameterCpatient = new OAParameter();
        parameterCpatient.ParameterName = "cpatient";
        parameterCpatient.Size = -1;
        if(cpatient != null)
        {
            parameterCpatient.Value = cpatient;
        }   
        else
        {
            parameterCpatient.DbType = DbType.String;
            parameterCpatient.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }

        OAParameter parameterO = new OAParameter();
        parameterO.ParameterName = "o";
        parameterO.Value = o;

        OAParameter parameterN = new OAParameter();
        parameterN.ParameterName = "n";
        parameterN.Value = n;

        int queryResult = this.ExecuteNonQuery("SELECT * FROM \"public\".\"g_savedx\"(cpatient, o, n)", CommandType.Text, parameterCpatient, parameterO, parameterN);
    
        return queryResult;
    }
```

Where the ExecuteNonQuery statement generates the error.  The PostgreSQL stored procedure is:

```
  FUNCTION g_savedx(cpatient character varying, o view_dx, n view_dx)
  RETURNS void AS ...
```

The postgreSQL function has been tested to work correctly from pgAdmin.

So where is the column "cpatient" coming from?? What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could get the Telerik EntitiesModel ExecuteNonQuery to work under any conditions. Hence the suggested code of:

```
        using (var cxt = new Nova.Data.Data())
        {
            cxt.SaveDx();
            cxt.SaveChanges();
        }
```

where cxt.SaveDx() is the domain model name for the postgresql g_savedx stored procedure, fails.

My eventual workaround for PostgreSQL is to use Npgsql directly as:

```
  public void SaveDx(View_dx dx, bool alldx = false)
    {
        using (var cxt = new Nova.Data.Data())
        {
            string connstring = cxt.Connection.ConnectionString;

            using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "g_savedx";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    NpgsqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
                    cmd.Parameters["groupid"].Value = ....

                 var rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When doing it this way, only use the types defined in the NpgsqlDbType enumeration in the PostgreSQL procedure interface. (PostgreSQL can use composite types, Npgsql not so much).

It would sure be nice for Telerik ExecuteNonQuery to work.